# SQL command to replace unicode characters with plain text

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode, replace

To export our database to excel (to import into another product), I need to remove Unicode characters. However, I know enough SQL to do this, which found a good number of products.

```
SELECT * FROM Products_TEST_Products WHERE CustomMemo01 LIKE '%*%'
```

I tried:

```
SELECT * REPLACE('*', '*', ' ') FROM Products_TEST_Products WHERE CustomMemo01 LIKE '%*%'
```

It didn't seem to do anything. I was hoping it would remove the asterisk with a space.  I'm simply trying to replace `*` with a space. When I tried the above code without the `LIKE '%*%'` I got the following error:

> "Error opening recordset in ConnOpenRecordset(): trapped error (-2147217900) Inccorect syntax near 'REPLACE' adoConnState=1 SQL=

And my code followed after `SQL=`.

I am ultimately trying to remove all Unicode with plain text for the export.

Comment: Note: I thought I had a return after the code LIKE '%*%' and "I tried SELECT"

Comment: Also the first option in the REPLACE needs to be the string column you're selecting so CustomMemo01, from what it seems - 
REPLACE(CustomMemo01, '*', ' ')

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try following (to avoid syntax error):

For unicode: add this `N'` just before `unicode` text value to recognize it has `unicode`

```
SELECT *, REPLACE(CustomMemo01, N'*', ' ') 
FROM   Products_TEST_Products 
--WHERE CustomMemo01 LIKE '%*%'
```

If you just want replace all `UNICODE` values and those are random, you can following as column:

```
replace (cast(CustomMemo01 as varchar(50)), '?', '') as NonUnicodeColumn
```

---

This script might help you to start with:

```
Use YourDatabase
go 

Create Table UnicodeTbl
(UnioCodevalue nvarchar(50),
 EngValue varchar(50) 
)
go


  Insert into UnicodeTbl 
 (EngValue, UnioCodevalue)
 values
 ('Some Text 1', N'Text Arabic: بعض النصوص' ),
 ('Some Text 2', N'Text Chinese: 一些文字' ),
 ('Some Text 3', N'Text Hindi: कुछ पाठ' ),
 ('Some Text 4', N'Text Japanese: テキスト' ),
 ('Some Text 5', N'Text Russian: Некоторый текст' )
 go

--- Conversion test ----------------------------------------------------------
--select    replace ( (cast(UnioCodevalue as varchar(50)) ), '?', '') as ReplacedUnicode,
--      *
--from UnicodeTbl
--go


-- Enables xp_cmdshell to execute DOS commands from T-SQL ------------------------------------------------------------
IF (select value_in_use from sys.configurations 
    where name = 'xp_cmdshell' 
    ) = 0
    BEGIN
        exec sp_configure 'show advanced option', 1;
        reconfigure;

        exec SP_Configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;
        Reconfigure ;
    END
go


-- Exports to CSV from a view ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Create view vw_Unocode as
select 'ReplacedUnicode' c1Header, 'EngValue' as c2Header
union  
select  replace ( (cast(UnioCodevalue as varchar(50)) ), '?', '') as ReplacedUnicode,
        EngValue
from UnicodeTbl
go

exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'mkdir C:\BCPTest'; --- Creates folder, you may change your own directory

exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 
'bcp "YourDatabase.dbo.vw_Unocode" out "C:\BCPTest\UnicodeView.csv" -S ".\SQLExpress" -T -c -t,'; 
go


--Drop Table UnicodeTbl
--Drop View vw_Unocode

exec SP_Configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0;
Reconfigure ;
go

exec sp_configure 'show advanced option', 0;
reconfigure;
go
```

Comment: I tried both of these in SQL Server.  The first I got under Results (No column name) and then showed me various rows. and I got 'NonUnicodeColumn' at Results with the second command.  When I did a search of all rows and tried copy and pasting them into excel, it still made 1 row into several rows in excel (which I was told was due to unicode in those CustomMemo01). No error code though.

Comment: Hi @themaster408, i'm not sure which tool you are using to export data from SQL to excel/csv format, you could maybe use `BCP` utility that comes by default with SQL Server installation. please have a look at my edited post,  added script with test case.